# There are some (hopefully faster) alternatives for dir on windows?

Tags: windows, powershell, terminal

Essentially, the title

I think that generally the `dir` command on Windows is too verbose and slow.

(And i'm starting to think that maybe write an alternative myself would be an option)

Comment: are you referring to `dir` (`Get-ChildItem`) from powershell or to `dir` command ?

Comment: You could certainly write your own, but there's no guarantee it would be faster.

Comment: @GovindParmar - `DIR /B` is the CMD form of `DIR`; it doesn't work in PowerShell (the equivalent would be `(Get-ChildItem).FullName`).

Comment: I was referring to `Get-ChildItem` from powershell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That kind of depends on what you need. Do you just want names of files? Do you want directories and files? Does it need to be recursive? If you're simply looking at basic `dir`, then in the context of PowerShell you can get much faster results from using the `DirectoryInfo` class's `GetFiles()` method. I pulled C:\Windows\System32 on my system 1000 times with `Get-ChildItem` and with both `GetDirectories()` and `GetFiles()`, and the .Net methods were much faster (about 7x faster).

```
1..1000|%{Measure-Command -Expression {Get-ChildItem C:\Windows\System32}} |Measure-Object -Average -Property TotalMilliseconds |% Average
142.9717982
1..1000|%{Measure-Command -Expression {([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:\Windows\System32').GetDirectories();([System.IO.DirectoryInfo]'C:\Windows\System32').GetFiles()}} |Measure-Object -Average -Property TotalMilliseconds |% Average
19.9039127
```

Again, that's just getting you directory names and file names for a single path, but if that's all that you're after it's a good alternative.

Comment: I suspect that part of the time taken by `Get-ChildItem` is to sort the results; does `[DirectoryInfo]::GetFiles()` return them sorted, or in raw order?

Comment: @JeffZeitlin not only that but also when attaching ETS properties to the objects

Comment: @JeffZeitlin it does appear to sort them, yes.

Comment: My question wasn't detailed at all, because i expected a response like will be on linux "yeah you can use [exa](https://github.com/ogham/exa) or [lsd](https://github.com/Peltoche/lsd) or ...". Still the answer is what i needed, a fast and easy way to get files and directory from a path.